# How to remove brackets from a word using regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

Hi I am trying to remove the brackets from a word like NAND[0] and I want the result to be NAND0. How do I code using regexp in Tcl.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the data from which you want to strip the brackets is in the variable `val` and have the transformed data stored in variable `result`

```
set result [regsub -all {\[|\]} $val ""]
```

You can also do

```
regsub -all {\[|\]} $val "" result
```

Comment: The above is correct but for simple substitution using 'string map' is more efficient and arguably more readble. `string map {\[ "" \] ""} $input`